# User Full Name Tag in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, tags

[image]I'm trying to implement a full name mention functionality in flutter , the solution I've come across so far work for usernames but no user fullname , can any one help with a solution ? Attach is an images that describes what I'm trying to achieve

I have tried the flutter_social_textfield package
[text](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_social_textfield) , this is closest to what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: Where is the attached image?

Comment: @mandy8055 I've attach an image now